# Setting standards on boundary length

Tags: cricket

When there is a standard length for cricket pitches,  why aren't there such standards for boundary sizes?

Answer (score 2):

The ICC do specify boundary sizes as do many competitons.   I would suggest the reason that the laws remain silent on this is the wide variety of sizes of ground from small chocolate box grounds to massive international fields.

Answer (score 1):

There hasn't been any fixed rules given by the International Cricket Council, but they have said that a ground should have a minimum size of 137 meters appromxicately 68 meters from either side of the pitch although it varies on whic pitch is used on the given day.
The shortest boundary should be around 60meters and longest one should be around 83 meters from the center of the pitch.Also the distance between the boundary ropes and the advertising boards should be mimimum 3 metres.Check this link
http://www.sportscourtdimensions.com/cricket/

Comment: Could you give some references to support this answer?